# regex expression for multiple matches for this=that in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How do I match this pattern multiple times in a string for all of them.

1=aa 2='bb' 3=" cc" 4="dd"

The regex should match all these and give 4 matches as
1) 1=aa 
2) 2='bb'
3) 3=" cc"
4) 4="dd"

I tried and so far I have this, `(?<number>\d=)\s*("|')?\s*(?<value>.*?)(?=\d=)`

This matches everything except the #4. It is because there is no `\d=` for the last one. I know I can make it optional by putting a ? at the end, but then it does not match anything correctly, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?=\d=)` part means "followed by `\d=`". What you need is `(?=\d=|$)`, which means "followed by `\d=` or end-of-string":

```
(?<number>\d=)\s*("|')?\s*(?<value>.*?)(?=\d=|$)
```